# Filter Pandas dataframe by column name on regex patterns using str.contains

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to find columns in a dataframe that match a string pattern. I specifically want to find two parts, firstly find a column that contains "WORDABC" and then I want to find the column that also is the "1" value of that column (i.e. "WORDABC1"). To do this I have been using the [.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) Pandas function.

**My problem is when there are two numbers, such as "11" or "13".**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'WORDABC1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'WORDABC11': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6},
 'WORDABC8N123': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9},
 'WORDABC81N123': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12},
 'WORDABC9N123': {0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15},
 'WORDABC99N123': {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18}})
```

Trying to search for the column that contains "WORDABC1" gives two results, "WORDABC1" and

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC1')]]

   WORDABC1  WORDABC11
0         1          4
1         2          5
2         3          6
```

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC1\\b')]]

   WORDABC1
0         1
1         2
2         3
```

For the above example, it works for me. However my problem happens if there are more characters after my found pattern.

```
df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC9')]]
   WORDABC9N123  WORDABC99N123
0            13             16
1            14             17
2            15             18

df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC9\\b')]]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]
```

I only want the "WORDABC9N123" column, and I cannot just remove the other column. I have considered just using `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC9')][0]]` to get the series I want, but that creates another issue.

I have also been using things such as `(df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'WORDABC1\\b')).sum()` to create truth statements, so the above `df[0]` method doesn't help me get through the issue.

**Is there a better method to use instead of str.contains? Or is my regex just incorrect? Thank you!**

Comment: It's unclear what the rules are. Is it just that there can be no additional numbers at the end of the pattern?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `.filter` with `regex=` parameter:

```py
print(df.filter(regex=r"WORDABC9(?=[^\d]|$)"))
```

Prints:

```
   WORDABC9N123
0            13
1            14
2            15
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. So for this expression, after finding WORDABC9, we do a positive lookahead where we look for 1 character that is not a digit, or its the end of the line. That makes a lot of sense. I will continue to practice more regex!

Answer (score 1):

`pat = 'WORDABC1\\b'` works when matching `'WORDABC1'` because `\\b` matches word boundaries, and the end of a string is a word boundary.

If you want to match `'WORDABC9N123'` but not `'WORDABC99N123'`, the similar pattern `'WORDABC9\\b'` will not work because there is no word boundary in either case.

I think you want to match `WORDABC9` followed by a non-digit, in which case you can try `pat = 'WORDABC9[\\b | \\D]'`. That will match either `WORDABC9` or `WORDABC9N...`, but not `WORDABC99N123`